# How to remove flash in an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using core image to apply a few filters to the CIImage.

There's a flash in the image which is quite annoying.

I've tried to use CIMedian Filter and CINoiseReduction filter. The filters were of little or no avail.

I've even tried to increase the contrast of the image, however, it reduces the accuracy of the image for OCR.

**Update:**

Currently I've increased the contrast the image and the result is great (only 1 word with slightly high brightness/ looks white doesn't get detected):

```
// Add filter increase the exposure
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:_inputImage.image];
CIFilter *exposureAdjustmentFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setDefaults];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exposureNumber] forKey:@"inputEV"]; //set it to 5.0 will be able to remove the background blue color, and make the black color text standout 
CIImage *outputImageAfterExposure = [exposureAdjustmentFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

@holex, I've tried to use the edge filter, but I couldn't get a desirable result since I don't really understand the inputIntensity parameter:

```
// Use edge detection filter
CIImage *inputImageEdgeDetection = outputImageAfterExposure;
CIFilter *ciEdges = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIEdges"];
[ciEdges setDefaults];
[ciEdges setValue:inputImageEdgeDetection forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[ciEdges setValue:@(5) forKey:@"inputIntensity"]; // what is this for?
CIImage *outputImageAfterEdgeDetection = [ciEdges valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

The Documentation is quite vague for inputIntensity: 
An NSNumber object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Intensity.
Default value: 1.00

Added image after CIEdge filter:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to do a simple _edge-detection_? that usually works with ORC together quite smoothly.

Comment: I've tried edge-detection, however the accuracy drops. Do you have any idea how to adjust the inputIntensity value? or is it caused by other issues?

Comment: Is there a way to remove blue color in an image? Because when I'm using edge detection the background has many blue lines which causes the inaccuracy.